# Jetpack Compose: Can't make statusBar completely transparent

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-statusbar

I have a screen, which contains a Map and I want to make a statusBar completely transparent.

What I've tried:

```kotlin
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.26.1-alpha"

@Composable
fun MapMainScreen() = Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    val controller = rememberSystemUiController()
    controller.setStatusBarColor(color = Color.Transparent)
    controller.setNavigationBarColor(color = Color.Transparent)
    controller.setSystemBarsColor(color = Color.Transparent)
    
    Map()
}
```

Also, I've tried to play with **window** in MainActivity before and in *setContent* call:

```kotlin
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
window.setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
)
```

I want to see a result like in Google Maps, but now my statusBar has a White-Gray color instead of Transparent

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this and make my statusBar Transparent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any additional dependency is not needed.

In your Compose theme (or directly in activity) set this:

```
SideEffect {
    with(view.context as Activity) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !darkTheme
        window.statusBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
        window.navigationBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
    }
}
```

Optionally, you could also add this line to make the navigation bar transparent:

```
window.navigationBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what Accompanist suggests in the [doc](https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/):

```
// Remember a SystemUiController
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
val useDarkIcons = !isSystemInDarkTheme()

DisposableEffect(systemUiController, useDarkIcons) {
    // Update all of the system bar colors to be transparent, and use
    // dark icons if we're in light theme
    systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
        color = Color.Transparent,
        darkIcons = useDarkIcons
    )

    // setStatusBarColor() and setNavigationBarColor() also exist

    onDispose {}
}
```

Also the latest version is : `0.26.3-beta`

Comment: updated the version to last & copy the code, doesn't work :(
 https://pasteboard.co/oawz5Sryzz4K.jpg